# Pass json string to argument parser python

Tags: python, json, command-line-arguments, argparse

try to pass json string  `--model-config {'campaign_id':100500,'run_id':1}` to parser:

```
parser = ArgumentParser(description="")
parser.add_argument(
    '--model-config',
    type=str,
    help='valid json string to set up model config'
)
```

But in this case I can't use spaces between property names and between key value pairs, otherwise I get an error:
`unrecognized arguments: 'run_id':1}`
Also I need to use double quotes (instead of single quotes) for property names. But when I use double quotes I also get an error.
Do we have more convenient way to process json string?

Comment: IIRC, you put it in quotes.

Answer (score 4):

Since JSON requires double quotes for string, wrap your option inside a single quote then pass the keys with double quotes. like:

```
'{"campaign_id":100500, "run_id":1}'
```

then your full command will be:

```sh
python yourfile.py --model-config '{"campaign_id":100500, "run_id":1}'
```

The option is in a valid format for JSON and can be deserialized with `json.loads`.

It is possible to use double quotes for the wrapper, but you need to escape the inside double quotes like:

```
"{\"campaign_id\":100500, \"run_id\":1}"
```

So I think first one is more convenient.